# Change text in popup exposed date filter

Tags: views

I have an exposed popup date filter that selects by day. When a user sees it, it looks has this text: May 28 2016.

Would I be able to edit it so that it would look like "May 28th, 2016"?
I am using drupal 7.23 and Views 3.13.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Drupal / Views?

Comment: I am using drupal 7.23 and Views 3.13.